# How do we detect if wifi becomes unavailable in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi, bonjour, nsnetservice

Is there any way that we can programatically identify when the wifi of a user becomes available/unavailable?

My application requires exchanging messages between two different devices. It is working good in stable wifi setups. But if the wifi is unstable, I am having trouble in detecting if the other device is available or not.

I am not sure if this is expected, but my bonjour based NSNetService discoverer is not updating the available devices list automatically. This leaves me with a list of services that are not available for the exchange.

My line of thinking was to remove all the available services from the list and start a fresh search.

Please let me know if I am thinking in the right direction to solve the right problem.

Thanks in advance.

-Murali

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/) sample code provided by Apple will help you in this regard. Although there have been people who say it hasn't been updated in a while, in which case, [here](http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24) is an actively maintained fork.

It seems like you can register for notifications so you can get frequent information on the state of the network.

Comment: This sounds very promising. I'll try to incorporate that and update how it goes.

Thank you very much, Blaenk. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The Reachability sample code provide by Apple was last updated July 20, 2010.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1